# How to get gate names for ned.DatarateChannel

Tags: omnet++

I am doing a process oriented simulation using omnet++. I am configuring my simulation from a NetworkBuilder module dynamically i.e. I am not using ned to set up connections between modules.

I have defined a ned.DatarateChannel to connect my components. How can I access its input and output gates from the C++ code of my NeworkBuilder module?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getSourceGate()` on the connection and then you can use `getPathStartGate()` and `getPathEndGate()` to access the gates at the beginning and end of a connection path between two simple modules.

API docs:
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cChannel.html#a6b5e1022a6124367e4eb19079a952f42

Comment: Thanks (I should RTFM first). Incidentally I found I could just use src->connectTo(dest, channel);